# If you remove something from an Array, will it get released from memory?

Tags: ios, swift

Assuming that nothing is referencing it anymore, will an object be released from memory after being removed from an array?

Should I set it to nil before removing it?

Comment: Yes, Swift uses ARC. If an object is added to an array and then removed. It will be cleared from memory. You will not need to it to nil before removing.

Comment: yes..it will be released from the memory...if not after removing item it should  have show the value again?

Comment: If nothing else is referencing it what would you set to nil?

Comment: its not removing actually immediate removing the objects in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will be released, Swift uses [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation//Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID49). If an object is added to an array and then removed. It will be cleared from memory. You will not need to it to nil before removing.